# Error when getting request in AWS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nsdata

I'm getting this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception `AmazonServiceException` , **reason**: '(null)'" when requesting to get object from S3 here is my code:

```
 AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID
                                                     withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
    S3TransferManager *tm = [S3TransferManager new];
    tm.s3 = s3;

    S3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"1234/history.json" withBucket:S3TRANSFERMANAGER_BUCKET];
    [s3 getObject:getObjectRequest];

    S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [s3 getObject:getObjectRequest];



    NSData *data = getObjectResponse.body;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArrayNewObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *jsonArrayHistoryObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *historyList = [jsonArrayHistoryObject mutableCopy];

    [historyList addObjectsFromArray:jsonArrayNewObject];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = [historyList mutableCopy];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                        dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                        options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                        error:&error];

    [self upload:jsonData];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look as the iOS Sample Application part of AWS iOS SDK : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples

It contains a S3 file transfer (upload and download) sample